# Ansible - lineinfile

Tags: ansible

I would like to use the lineinfile module to automatically fill an inventory file (inventory/hosts) from another inventory file that I use to deploy VMs on vsphere.

When the file is empty, there is no problem but, when it is already filled, the module does not insert the lines when it sees that they exist elsewhere in the file. But I need it to build my inventory file.

How I can do this?

Here is my piece of code:

```
- name: Add parameters for connection of VMs Windows
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /home/ansible/inventory/hosts
    line: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: 
    - '[{{ group_names[0] }}:vars]'
    - ansible_user=administrator
    - ansible_password='{{ lookup('file', '/home/ansible/directory/file_'+group_names[0] ) }}'
    - ansible_connection=winrm
    - ansible_port=5986
    - ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
  delegate_to: localhost
```

It only inserts the `ansible_password` line for me, since the others exist for other groups of VMs. I also tried with blockinfile

Comment: Well, if the other lines besides the password already exist in that file, then that's usually what you want - Ansible tries its best to be idempotent in that it won't make changes unless it has to.  Have you tried, for sanity's sake, to change one of those constants? Instead of "adminstrator" try "emperor" to see that the file does change that line and also add the password.

Comment: What about simply dumping those vars as yaml  to `/home/ansible/inventory/group_vars/{{ group_names[0] }}/my_connection_vars.yml`?

Comment: @Makoto, 
I tried with another login, other than administrator and the line "ansible_user=emperor" was added but not the others since they exist for other groups of VMs.

I wanted to automatically build the inventory file that would allow me to run the VM configuration playbooks after their deployment

Comment: @Zeitounator i will test your solution and come back to you

Comment: Note: if you expect those vars to be available within the same playbook where you create/modify them (whether you reference them in the inventory file directly on in a host/group vars inventory file..), you will need to [`- meta: refresh_inventory`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html) at some point.

Comment: @Zeitounator et Makotor, thanks for your answers
I was able to find a solution, since the groups of Vms that I want to add automatically in my inventory file are "child" groups I just need to put the common parameters on the "parent" group. which gives in my case:
`
[windows]
win_web
win_db

[windows:vars]
ansible_user=administrator
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_port=5986
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore

[win_web]
vm-01

[win_web:vars]
ansible_password='password'

[win_db]
vm-02

[win_db:vars]
ansible_password='password02'
`
which solves my problem

Comment: @Nicolas This should be in a self answer to your question, not in a comment.